# My app was rejected citing 11.3 (In-app purchase)

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I created an app that lets users store items in the app. There is an amazon button next to each item. When the user clicks the amazon button, the app finds the item on amazon and, if found, opens the amazon page for the item WITH-IN the app.

Apple rejected the app citing 11.3 in-app purchase reasons.

would it help if the amazon page for the item opened in safari and not with-in the app?

Answer (score 1):

Read through the other points of the App Store Review Guidelines under [Section 11. Purchasing and currencies](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies). One more that stands out for your situation is this:

> **11.13** Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

So while you could provide a link that will open in Safari (instead of opening the page in-app), if that purchase will be used in your app in some way, it's likely to get rejected by citing this clause.

Also keep in mind that any interpretation here or elsewhere of single line policy statements to provide a clear "yes" or "no" to questions may not be final. It's Apple's interpretation that actually matters.

Comment: Once the user buys the product, that product is never "used" inside the app. For example; if they stored an item called chair and then clicked on amazon link and from the amazon website bought an actual chir...that chair wouldn't be used inside the app. I understand its Apple's interpretation. What should I do at this moment? Should I reply back to them asking whether not opening the link inside the app will help?

Comment: @Omnipresent — What are the items ? Virtual items for a game ? Or real items like a real chair ?

Comment: It could be both, depending on what the user stores. If a user stores "Coldplay" then clicks amazon button then the amazon link will be for an MP3. If they store a "chair" then the amazon link will go to a physical chair. The app gets the amazon links from Amazon API based on the item name that the user has stored.

Comment: I think your best bet is to modify your app first to remove that Buy button that violates article 11.3 of the guidelines/policies. Turn that into a link that would open in Safari, preferably with a different text, like "View on Amazon". If Apple still rejects it, you could write to them and clarify the situation. As it stands now, 11.3 is your first barrier.

Comment: @MK - Opening the page in the app is better than in Safari. Thus the user remains in the app. Triggering Safari in annoying at best, and it can steal user pages.

Comment: @Omnipresent - Apple wants that the purchases be made within the app, with the App Store billing. Apple is the king of the world 'cos' Apple has the billing. This gives a commission to Apple. This also gives a nicer user experience. As for proposing to the user to buy real objects from Amazon according to the stored (virtual) items, I don't think that this would be very pertinent. With doing so from Sim City, I would have filled my house with chairs and leeks until the ceiling!

Answer (score 0):

I think that Apple wants you to “allow” users to buy items *with Apple’s billing system*, not with Amazon.

When you have the billing, you are the king of world. This made the success of Apple’s ecosystem of apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom API for the purchases with amazon. You can't use apple's IAP for this because they already have a default avenue for ebook sales.